# Do I have to explicitly create an `ApplicationView` and an `ApplicationController` for every Ember.js application?

Tags: ember.js

From [Trek's tutorial:](http://trek.github.com/)

> Your application must have an ApplicationView property. An instance of
>   this class will be created for you and inserted into the application's
>   view hierarchy as the root view.

And the tutorial gives this example code:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
```

What is special about `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController`? Is their particular name reserved and must be used by conversion or is there something special about the way the router refers to them?

As I understand it, one of Ember's principals is to eliminate boilerplate code. So I am guessing there is something more to explicitly creating these two views for every app as starting point -- otherwise Ember would just make them for me behind the scene.

To rephrase my question, what makes `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` special in an Ember application. Do I need to create them explicitly for every app and if so, do I need to name them following a convention?

Note: I am using ember-latest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember.js tries to adhere to the programming philosophy of convention over configuration. Because of this some things need to be specifically named and follow correct casing rules. Upon calling `App.initialize()` your application looks for the property on itself `App.ApplicationView`. Your app then renders this view, inserts it into the dom and auto-creates an instance of `App.ApplicationController`, setting it as the render context for your `ApplicationView`. This means that any properties in your `ApplictationController` can be bound in your `ApplicationView` simply by referencing them in the view.

If you call `App.initialize()` with out an `App.ApplicationView` or `App.ApplicationController` ember will throw an error letting you know you must create them.

`ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` are integral parts of your ember application and must exist. Ember is an MVC framework, `ApplicationView` is your root V, `ApplicationController` is your root C. It can be tempting to try to use frameworks like ember for just the pieces that you want, but with just a little more work you'll have a much more robust, and easy to use application that trying to cherry pick functionality.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation. Do you have any reference or sample code that shows ember will throw an error if there is no `App.ApplicationView` defined? The reason is that I have not defined it in any of my jsFiddles so far and I dont see an error.

Comment: Also I think ember-latest has removed the need to call `App.initialize()` by setting `autoinit` to `true`. Does that have an effect on this scenario?

Comment: @Aras No, this should not have an effect. The application is auto-initialized, but always requires ApplicationView and ApplicationController