# Ember.js render into view's outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I've got a view that has a named outlet inside of it. This view is not associated with a controller and cannot be for my use case. I seem to be unable to render into that named outlet. How would I correctly target it?

If the view is named `App.UnassociatedView`, the named outlet is `{{outlet potatoOutlet}}`, and the controller and view that I wish to associate are `App.PotatoController` and `App.PotatoView` respectively, how do I make this work?

I've tried

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render('potato', {outlet: 'potatoOutlet', controller: this.controllerFor('potato')});
    }
});
```

This

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render('potato', {outlet: 'potatoOutlet', controller: this.controllerFor('potato'), into: 'application'});
    }
});
```

And This

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render('potato', {outlet: 'potatoOutlet', controller: this.controllerFor('potato'), into: 'unassociated'});
    }
});
```

Here is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/X8Mu4/

**Edit for clarity**

I had this in my comment text in the fiddle, but forgot to put it here. Moving the outlet into the root level isn't an option for me b/c the goal of this is to have the `UnassociatedView` actually generate outlets at page load time. My code to make the outlets actually works, I just can't connect them.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this up your jsfiddle somewhat.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this._super();
    var controller = this.controllerFor('potato');
    this.render('potato', {outlet: 'potatoOutlet', controller: controller});
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8Mu4/5/

- Moved outlet to root level
- Moved renderTemplate override to IndexRoute (as that is what is routed to)
- Enabled LOG_TRANSITIONS to aid debugging routing

I'd recommend not overriding ApplicationView's template as index. Leads to confusion.

You also do not have to explicitly create the ApplicationView. See: [Do I have to explicitly create an `ApplicationView` and an `ApplicationController` for every Ember.js application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712122/do-i-have-to-explicitly-create-an-applicationview-and-an-applicationcontrolle)

Comment: Ah, so the problem here is that the unassociated-view in practicality actually dynamically creates N number views at load time, so the outlet must not be at the root level and must reside within that view. thanks for your help and time though!