# Why didInsertElement hook trigger before elements rendered inside {{#each}} block?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember, I want to add some query DOM manipulation code to the element in the `{{#each}}` block. So I google it up and found the solution from [this guide](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/):

**views/products/index.js**

```
import Spinner from 'appkit/utils/someJqueryCode';

Ember.View.reopen({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  },
  afterRenderEvent : function(){
    // implement this hook in your own subclasses and run your jQuery logic there
  }
});

export default Ember.View.extend({
  afterRenderEvent: function() {
    Spinner();
  }
});
```

---

**templates/products/index.hbs**

```
<div class='panel panel-default products'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h2 class='panel-title'>Our Prodcuts</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <ul class='row'>
        {{#each}}
            <li class='col-md-4'>
    <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img {{bind-attr src=url alt=alt}} />
    </div>
    <div class='caption'>
        <h3 class='name-me'>{{name}}</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <div class='row no-gutter'>
            <div class='col-xs-3'>
                <button class='btn btn-primary'>Buy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
        {{/each}}
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I seems after the point when `afterRenderEvent()` is triggered, all the elements in the `{{#each}}` block hasn't been rendered to the DOM yet, thus, the jQuery code return undefined

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: @JordyLangen I've updated the code of view and templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view's `didInsertElement` hook will fire as soon as the application route is rendered, which happens before the index route. You might think that putting it in the index.js file will work, but it's going to just extend the default application view behavior.

You need to create a more focused view that lives within your index.hbs file. One that is only concerned with your spinner jQuery doohickey. That, and an each/else conditional could work nicely here. For example:

```
{{#each}}
  {{#view App.SpinnerDoohickeyView}}
  <li class='col-md-4'>
    <div class='thumbnail'>
      <img {{bind-attr src=url alt=alt}} />
    </div>
    <div class='caption'>
      <h3 class='name-me'>{{name}}</h3>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
      <div class='row no-gutter'>
        <div class='col-xs-3'>
          <button class='btn btn-primary'>Buy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  {{/view}}
{{else}}
  <li>Empty collection!</li>
{{/each}}
```

Notice that I've wrapped each list item in its own view. You could wrap the whole `ul` if you wanted... this is just an example. The idea is that you are only creating views when you have a model.

And now you can define the view, and simply use the `didInsertElement` hook to work with jQuery:

```
App.SpinnerDoohickeyView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.$('li').css('background', 'blue');
  }
});
```

If you have a model to render, jQuery should be able to safely access it this way. Good luck!

Here's some further reading and some code from the Ember folks that looks like what I've shown you here: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/

Comment: @mko When you extended the view in your code, you didn't specify a particular scope within your application. Thus, it fired its hooks while on the application route, before your index model had a chance to render. Thus, your jQuery couldn't find the DOM elements.

Comment: `1.` Routes aren't responsible for rendering. Views are. In your case, you extended the base application view. `2.` No, it refers to the very base view that wraps the entire ember application. It doesn't show up in the templates because ember creates it on its own. `3.` I mean the base application view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712122/do-i-have-to-explicitly-create-an-applicationview-and-an-applicationcontrolle

Comment: After reading your first comment. I was starting to make sense to me. So I delete the question. I'll try to change the code, so how it works. Thank you again

Comment: @mko For sure, let me know if you need any additional help!